# Pegando nome de usuário (windows)

Tags: c#

Olá
Estou tentando pegar o nome do usuário logado no windows, algo que obtive sucesso com o

```
Environment.UserName
```

porém, quando eu publico a aplicação, o nome que me retorna é "DotNetCore", que é um usuário criado pelo SKD.
Tem alguma forma que pego do usuário mesmo?

Answer (score -1):

Tente capturar o nome do usuário logado na máquina

`string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

Comment: Não deu certo.. agora voltou como resultado isso: 
"IIS APPPOOL\DotNetCore"

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa que a sua aplicação esteja configurada para fazer autenticação integrada no windows

[Segue exemplo de configação](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhqe4.png)

No caso, esse dotnetcore ou coisa do tipo é pq a autenticação está habilitada para anonymous.